# Buying FedEx shipping label through EasyPost

Tags: fedex, easypost

I'm having troubles buying FedEx shipping label through EasyPost.
I was trying to buy label for FedEx International Economy service and received the following error message from EasyPost:

Shipment: shp_XXX, message: Validation failed: Predefined package Invalid predefined package type.

I didn't set any predefined packages, maybe this is the problem and I must enter predefined package along with weight only?

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: This is a great question that could be directed to our support team via support@easypost.com

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your call?

It looks like you're included a predefined_package which is only available for another carrier.